# Question with sendmail on CentOS

Tags: centos, sendmail

I get an error when I restart sendmail on my CentOS server, and it can not send email out. The error is :

```
[root@centos sendmail-8.13.6]# service sendmail restart
close sm-client：                                           [success]
close sendmail：                                            [failt]
start sendmail：554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 152: readcf: map mailertable: class hash not available
554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 155: readcf: map virtuser: class hash not available
554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 160: readcf: map access: class hash not available
Warning: Option: AuthOptions requires SASL support (-DSASL)
                                                           [failt]
start sm-client：                                           [success]
```

Comment: How did you generate the sendmail.cf file being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sendmail FAQ:

What does "class hash not available" mean?

http://www.sendmail.org/faq/section3#3.31

I'd try to figure out if this install of sendmail was done with some customizations for some reason.

Post your sendmail.cf and we'll take a look.

Comment: it works now, but it can not send email out :(

Answer (score 0):

What you post is odd, because when I restart sendmail on a CentOS 5.6 box, what I get is:

```
[madhatta@www ~]$ sudo service sendmail restart
Shutting down sm-client:                                   [  OK  ]
Shutting down sendmail:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting sm-client:                                        [  OK  ]
```

Which makes me wonder if you're running some kind of hand-built sendmail - because the packaged version does.  Before anything else, could we get the output of `rpm -qf /etc/init.d/sendmail` and the version of CentOS you're running?

**Edit**: thanks for those.  Could you also confirm that you're not running any kind of hand-hacked sendmail, perhaps with `rpm -qV sendmail`?

**Edit 2**: in the light of dmourati's excellent observation, can we see what your sendmail is compiled with?  A quick way to do this is to **cut-and-paste** (*please, don't just retype*) the output from `sendmail -bt -d3,0`.

Comment: sendmail-8.13.8-8.el5

Comment: and i am using centos 5.5